# SQL Developer - can't connect, listener does not currently know of SID/service name

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I know this is a common problem, I've tried everything I could find online and nothing solved my problem. I even uninstalled Oracle 11g XE and SQL Developer, deleted every file I could find and reinstalled, didn't help anything.

I can connect perfectly through the SQL*Plus command line and CMD.

I never had this problem but since today, when I try to connect with DQL Developer I keep getting this error:

[image: Error]

AND

[image]

This is my tnsnames.ora file:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-5MFACN6)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

listener.ora file:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-5MFACN6)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Output from some tests from SQL*Plus:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XE

SQL> select instance from v$thread;

INSTANCE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xe

SQL> select host_name,instance_name,version from v$instance;

HOST_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------
INSTANCE_NAME    VERSION
---------------- -----------------
DESKTOP-5MFACN6
xe               11.2.0.2.0


SQL> select global_name from global_name;

GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XE
```

and listener status:

```
C:\Users\Arne>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 23-OCT-2018 18:27:07

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                23-OCT-2018 18:19:35
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 7 min. 31 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-5MFACN6\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-5MFACN6)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I really don't know what I can do anymore

Comment: Does `DESKTOP-5MFACN6` resolve to the same as localhost, i.e. 127.0.0.1? WHat happens if you use that name for the connection in SQL Developer instead?

Comment: I was even so desperate to try that, but that didnt work. ... but ... I turned off my computer, went away for a bit and when I was back I tried again, for some reason it worked again... ! Weird because restarting didn't do anything before. Now it is fixed for some reason. Such a relief. Hope it stays this way now because it need to get some work done. :)

Comment: Restarting your laptop would mean your listener was restarted, which is what was probably required.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I don't see a service listed, I run an alter system register which flushes the servicenames to the listener vs waiting on the listner to poll and find them itself

```
$ sql  / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 13 14:17:28 2018
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter system register;

System altered.

SQL>
```